# Batch File scripting -Iteration through GrandParentfolder and deploy the packges

Tags: batch-file

I have struture like

```
E:\X\Y\z\File1.dtsx
E:\X\Y\z\File2.dtsx
E:\X\M\z\File3.dtsx
E:\X\M\z\File4.dtsx...
```

I want to iterate through the folder which contains .dtsx files and get its grandparent folder name [i,e] in this case I need to get 'Y'and 'M' and then deploy in Integration services with Folder as Y -File1 and File2 where as in Folder 'M' File3 and File 4.
ie.

```
------------------Folder y-----------
      --File1.
      --File2
------------------Folder m-----------
      --File3.
      --File4----
```

--And so on 
i.e Grandparent folder Name varies --Parent folder is consistent --Depending on grand folder name under suto subfolder packges exist. I need to iterate through grand folder and get the .dtsx files and I need to deploy them in Integration service  with folder name as  grandfolder name.

Comment: I've fixed (I hope) some of the formatting problems - and I'm not the only one to attempt it. Left a couple out, too - not sure whether 'suto' should be 'auto' but I can't see how that would help :(. Still, no criticism of brave attempt in an unfamiliar language. I'd not do as well in yours... Just not sure what is required, but I'll give it a shake...

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: starting directory
SET "relroot=u:"
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( 'dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\*.dtsx" ') DO (
 FOR /f "delims=" %%m IN ("%%~dpi.") DO (
  FOR /f "delims=" %%q IN ("%%~dpm.") DO (
   ECHO "%%~nxi" "%%~nq"
  )
 )
)
)>"%temp%\tempfile_name"
SORT "%temp%\tempfile_name" >"%temp%\tempfile_anothername"
GOTO :EOF
```

Here's a starter.

The file `"%temp%\tempfile_name"` should contain lines of the format

```
"file3.dtsx" "m"
```

The file `"%temp%\tempfile_anothername"` should contain those lines, sorted so that they are in alphabetical sequence of the filename.

Not sure whether the quotes are required, the sequence of elements required, the sequence of output that's required, or whether you need the `"z"` directory as well (It's available as `%%~nm`)

---

addendum following comments 20130703-1355Z

Oh, my! Confusion regins!

Stackexchange's periodic inbox-notification includes a small portion of comments posted, and reads on two successive reports:

... ,D:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity\Folder\File1_1.dtsx ;

... D:\Data Migration\DX\AE_Deployment_SAT\20-Interfaces\Flex Att Per

Yet the second of these does NOT appear in the currently-available comments.

Here's a batch I used to create the files reported in the current comments - all I've done is edit the drive-letter - I've even left the `Entity` as posted rather than `Entity1` as narrated:

```
@echo off
setlocal
del /s u:\*.dtsx
md "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity\Folder" 2>nul
md "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity1\Folder" 2>nul
md "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder" 2>nul
copy nul "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity\Folder\File1_1.dtsx
copy nul "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity1\Folder\File1_2.dtsx"
copy nul "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder\File1_3.dtsx"
copy nul "U:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder\File1_4.dtsx"
dir/s u:\*.dtsx
```

Results:

```
u:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity\Folder\File1_1.dtsx
u:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity1\Folder\File1_2.dtsx
u:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder\File1_3.dtsx
u:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder\File1_4.dtsx
```

running the batch I posted originally adding `"%%~nm"` on the `ECHO` line, with the amendment

```
...
SORT "%temp%\tempfile_name" >"%temp%\tempfile_anothername"
type "%temp%\tempfile_name" 
echo================================
TYPE "%temp%\tempfile_anothername"
GOTO :EOF
```

Results are:

```
"File1_1.dtsx" "Entity" "Folder"
"File1_2.dtsx" "Entity1" "Folder"
"File1_3.dtsx" "Entity2" "Folder"
"File1_4.dtsx" "Entity2" "Folder"
===============================
"File1_1.dtsx" "Entity" "Folder"
"File1_2.dtsx" "Entity1" "Folder"
"File1_3.dtsx" "Entity2" "Folder"
"File1_4.dtsx" "Entity2" "Folder"
```

So - works for me. No idea of what you actually want to produce, and unfortunately you seem to be censoring the results. I can only work with the data you provide... :(

Comment: Hi peter,Above solution is displying empty screnn

Comment: Yes - the output is in the files `"%temp%\tempfile_name"` and `"%temp%\tempfile_anothername"`. You'd need to `type` them to show the results. You would also need to change `relroot` to `E:` - I set up some files on my `u:` drive for testing.

Comment: Hi peter,D:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity1\File1_1.dtsx

Comment: Hi peter,D:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity\Folder\File1_1.dtsx  ;                                       D:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity1\Folder\File1_2.dtsx  ;                                              D:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder\File1_3.dtsx   ;                                             D:\Folder 1\SubFolder1\SubFolder2\_SubFolder3\SubFolder4\Entity2\Folder\File1_4.dtsx ;o/p is displaying File1_1,File1_2 entity1 but File1_3,File1_4 are diplaying subfolder4 it should display Entity2

Answer (score 2):

Nice job for `delayed expansion`:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
SET LF=^


REM do not touch two empty lines
FOR /R "E:\X" %%a IN (*.dtsx) DO call:doit "%%~a"
goto:eof

:doit
SET "fpath=%~1"
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET fpath=%fpath:\="!LF!"%
FOR %%b IN ("%fpath%") DO (
    SET "path2=!path1!"
    SET "path1=!fname!"
    SET "fname=%%~b"
)
ECHO file is "%fname%", father is "%path1%", grandfather is "%path2%".
ENDLOCAL
goto:eof
```

Comment: @user2545157 I made an edit. Please give always all needed information in your question.